# How do I count total lines of remote git repository

Tags: linux, git, bash

I wanna count to total lines of codes in git repository. 
I've found the answer in google.

`git ls-files -z  | xargs -0 cat | wc -l`

It works well in local repository.

but. 
I want to count in remote repository.

so, I tried.

`git ls-files -z /home/bjyoo/repositories/root/localfiletest.git | xargs -0 cat | wc -l`

,

`git ls-files -z --git-dir=/home/bjyoo/repositories/root/localfiletest.git | xargs -0 cat | wc -l`

and

`git --git-dir=/home/bjyoo/repositories/root/localfiletest.git --ls-files | xargs -0 cat | wc -l`

all command failed.

does anyone knows how to count total lines of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While VonC is correct on the reason why your commands are failing, there still is a way  to count the lines in a repository, even if this repository is bare.

For this to work you have to make git print the content of the files from a specific revision which is possible using `git show`.

Such a command could look like this, assuming you are currently in the repository.

```sh
for file in $(git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD); do
    git show HEAD:"$file"
done | wc -l
```

If you want to execute the command from a different folder you can use `--git-dir` after the `git` keyword.

```sh
for file in $(git --git-dir=<path-to-repo> ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD); do
    git --git-dir=<path-to-repo> show HEAD:"$file"
done | wc -l
```

---

We are using `git ls-tree` to list all files in the repository, the reason being that `ls-files` doesn't work in a bare repository. Then we print the content of the file using `git show` combined with a specific revision.

You can take a look at the [ls-tree documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-tree.html) and the [show documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html) to understand exactly what the commands are doing.

Answer (score 0):

`git log --numstat --no-merges --pretty="format:" | grep -v -e '^$' | awk -F " " '{sum+=$1-$2} END {print sum}'`